# asp.net mvc 4 [HttpPost] not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC 4. i have some problems dealing with attributs

i use `[httppost]` attribut in my controller but  it's not working

it's not even  invoked

my controller

```
    public ActionResult Inscription()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscription(Candidat candidat)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(candidat);

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my view

```
     @model ProcRec.Models.Candidat

     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Inscription";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
      }


      @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
     <div class="form_settings">
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscription", "CandidatController"))
      { 

      <table ="#FFFFFF">
      <tr>

      <td>@*<span >Nom :</span>*@ @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom_candidat)</td>

      <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nom_candidat)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.nom_candidat)     

             .

             .

       </table>

       }
  <input type="submit"  class="submit right"  value="Inscription" />
```

think you for your help

Comment: @Saranga...i was just trying to answer the problem completely..i caught two issues so i corrected them by my answer and submit button should be inside form is also there in my answer..and i answered before andy's answer... thankzz...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just correct beginform as :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Inscription", "CandidatController",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  ........
  <input type="submit"  class="submit right"  value="Inscription" /> 
}
```

Put submit button inside BeginForm() and give BeginForm() FormMethod as Post.

Thankzz..

Answer (score 3):

Put your `<submit>` element inside the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    ...
    <input type="submit"  class="submit right"  value="Inscription" /> 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to change `Html.BeginForm`. By default it's POST.

Check : [FormExtensions.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Only issue is with the submit button, it should be inside form as mentioned in [Andy Refuerzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180895/1926540). Don't know why it is down-voted.