# Error when adding [HttpPost] in my action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Please I need some help, on the adding new movie. I am facing an issue with `[HttpPost]` and I really don't know if it from it or not, but when I remove `[HttpPost]` the page is working.

My NewMovie View:

```
@model Vildy4.ViewModels.MovieFormViewModel
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewMovie";
}

<h2>New Movie</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewMovie", "Movies"))
{
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReleaseDate, "{0: d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genres)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GenresId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "Select Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberInStock)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberInStock, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NumberInStock)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

My Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult NewMovie(Movie movie)
       {
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               var viewModel = new MovieFormViewModel(movie)
               {
                   Genres = _context.Genres.ToList()
               };

               return View("NewMovie", viewModel);
           }

           if (movie.Id == 0)
           {
               movie.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
               _context.Movies.Add(movie);
           }
           else
           {
               var movieInDb = _context.Movies.Single(m => m.Id == movie.Id);
               {

                   movieInDb.Name = movie.Name;
                   movieInDb.Genre = movie.Genre;
                   movieInDb.ReleaseDate = movie.ReleaseDate;
                   movieInDb.DateAdded = movie.ReleaseDate;
                   movieInDb.NumberInStock = movie.NumberInStock;
               }
           }
           _context.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movies");

       }
```

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description:HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: `/Movies/NewMovie`

When I remove [HttpPost] it is working normally, but I can not post.

I checked many threads (e.g. [asp.net mvc 4 [HttpPost] not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180818/asp-net-mvc-4-httppost-not-working)) but it does not solve the issue.

I have another Controller with almost the same action and it works perfect.

Movie model:

```
 public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre")]
        [Required]
        public byte GenresId { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1,20)]
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

    }
```

MovieFormViewModel code:

```
public class MovieFormViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre")]
        [Required]
        public byte? GenresId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
        [Range(1, 20)]
        [Required]
        public int? NumberInStock { get; set; }


        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return Id != 0 ? "Edit Movie" : "New Movie";
            }
        }

        public MovieFormViewModel()
        {
            Id = 0;
        }

        public MovieFormViewModel(Movie movie)
        {
            Id = movie.Id;
            Name = movie.Name;
            ReleaseDate = movie.ReleaseDate;
            NumberInStock = movie.NumberInStock;
            GenresId = movie.GenresId;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Headers:

Request URL: http://localhost:3593/Movies/NewMovie
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3593
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

here is also the route in my application, which is the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

on the Source Page after getting the error, I noticed that I am getting the below Exception:

```
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;NewMovie&#39; was not found on controller &#39;Vildy4.Controllers.MoviesController&#39;.
```

I also searched but I could not find the solution, because action is there in the controller and when i do [HttpGet] it is working only [HttpPost] not working!

Comment: Dear @mjwills 
I have only one route which is the default
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Please show us the request headers for the response that is 404ing. This is available in Chrome Developer Tools, network tab. Please also `View Source` on the web page in Chrome. Then copy and paste `<div class="form-group">` **and the previous 6 lines and the next 6 lines** from `View Source` and include that in your question.

Comment: What is the name of the class / controller that contains the `NewMovie` endpoint? Are there any errors showing in `ErrorList` in Visual Studio when you compile?

Comment: @omarkkk How are you making the request? Seems like you are doing a GET and you need to do a POST

Comment: @AmanB That is also strange to me when check request header, I am getting Get whereas I doing post and declaring [httppost] on my action.

Comment: Please read through my comments and answer the other questions as well (e.g. View Source).